# Is it possible to create a sieve rule to sort existing emails?

Tags: email, email-filter, sieve-rules, sieve

I have made a (*very*) simple `sieve` script to sort incoming emails, but I was wondering if it is possible to sort existing emails into folders using sieve? I'm very new to sieve and I couldn't find resources online on whether this was possible or not.

```sieve
require ["fileinto"];

if address :is "from" ["email1@email.com", "email2@email.com", "email3@email.com", "email4@email.com"]
{
    fileinto "Family";
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: What mail server are you using?

Comment: @DavidPostill I am using ProtonMail.

Comment: After a brief look at the documentation it looks like sieve works on incoming mail only. Normal filters work on all emails.

Comment: Aw, bummer. Alright, I'll close the issue. Thank you for your help. EDIT: looks like I can't. Should I leave it as is, then?

Comment: Proton Mail now supports running sieve on existing mail. It's in the drop down next to the filter (at least on Mail Plus accounts).